# changing SSH port in GCP caused refuse to connect

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I login to compute engine instance using ssh. Then I change the port of my ssh into 12345 on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I save it and restart the service with `systemctl restart sshd`.

Next when I logout and login again, it has a message like this:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 12345
```

I tried it with port 22, it has the same result:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
```

then I tried to login with google cloud console in browser with a custom port. It not works too. It said this on the popup:

```
Connection failed
You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error. Wait a few moments and then try again.
```

How to access my VM when I can't connect via SSH and via Google Console?

Comment: Connection reset means you are getting past firewalls but the listener refuses to talk to you. Use the serial console feature to connect and then review the startup logs. Also review the logs from the Open SSH server. The log files will help you figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable the 12345 port in your server firewall before changing the port in sshd_config?

If port 12345 is blocked on the server, you may receive this type of error.

Comment: If a firewall is blocking a port, "Connection Timed Out" occurs.

Comment: I don't configure the firewall before. Then can it be open in Google Console?

Comment: Now it works. I need to configure `VCP Network > Firewall` first to open 12345 port. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If the above else fails, you can also try to enable 'Serial Console' for the VM. Then open up the VM details, and you will see an option for the Serial Console login there (least as of this writing).

As I locked myself out but had success with this, hope it helps someone else!